# Why does this ng-show is always truty?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a parameter called `isNEC`, it is easier set to '1' or '0'.
I have the following ng-show directive in my HTML:

```
<div ng-show="isNEC == 'anything'">should not be shown</div>
```

I always see the above div.

Can someone tell me what I am missing please?

Comment: Its hard to tell based on single line of code. Add more code / details. Better yet, provide MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use `*ngIf` instead of `ng-show`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if instead of ng-show

```
<div ng-if="isNEC == 'anything'">should not be shown</div>
```

also if you are using ng-show, you should use === instead of ==

```
<div ng-show="isNEC === 'anything'">should not be shown</div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.isNEC = "anything";
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
 
  <div ng-hide="isNEC == 'anything'">should not be shown</div>

</body>
```

Comment: <div ng-show="isNEC === 'anything'">should not be shown</div>

Comment: same results with ===

Comment: actually you should use ng-hide not ng-show if you dont want to see the div. check the sample

Comment: Angular4 your suggestion of ng-hide is always showing even when the test should be falsy

Comment: is thois angular4? or angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks ok. I would suggest you to print the value of "isNEC" on the DOM and check if it is actually set as expected